# Scrolling into -y and -x of overflowed image

Tags: html, css, overflow, transform

I have an image that scales when I hover over it, the excess image is hidden (see example code).

I want the image to scale from the centre so I use `transform-origin: 50% 50%`

The problem is; I want to be able to drag/scroll around the whole image in its transformed state, however, I can't scroll up or to the left of the centre of the image.

If I use `transform-origin: 0% 0%` I can see the whole image but (obviously) it no longer transforms from the centre of the image.

Any suggestions on how I can access the -y and -x space of the image whilst keeping the `transform-origin` in the centre?

```css
/* Map Image
  –––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– */
#MapBase {
  position: relative;
  left: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  max-width: 450px;
  max-height: 550px;
  z-index: 1;
  visibility: visible;
  overflow: scroll;
  }

#MapBase img {
  display: block;
  transition: transform .6s;
}
#MapBase:hover img {
  transform: scale(2);
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
}
```

```html
<div id="MapBase" class="map-container map-base dragscroll">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/450x550" class="map">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was lucky enough to find someone who had a fix for this problem. I'll share the code below for anyone who might land here with a similar request.

I've replaced the names of things my code used with `myArray1` `myArray2`, please someone correct me if this is the incorrect terminology.

```js
const myArray1 = document.querySelector('#');
const myArray2 = document.querySelector('#');
let hovering = false;
myArray1.addEventListener('mousemove', () => {
  if (hovering) {
    return;
  }

  myArray2.style.zoom = '200%';
  myArray1.scrollTo({
    top: myArray1.scrollHeight / 4,
    left: myArray1.scrollWidth / 4,
  });

  hovering = true;
})

myArray1.addEventListener('mouseleave', () => {
  hovering = false;
  myArray2.style.zoom = '100%';
  myArray1.scrollTo({
    top: myArray1.scrollHeight / 4,
    left: myArray1.scrollWidth / 4,
  })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can increase `height` and `width` of `img` on hover to the amount of scale like you scaled 2 times so `height/width` value increased to 200%

```css
/* Map Image
  –––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– */
#MapBase {
  position: relative;
  left: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  max-width: 450px;
  max-height: 550px;
  z-index: 1;
  visibility: visible;
  overflow: scroll;
  }

#MapBase img {
  display: block;
  transition: transform .6s;
}
#MapBase:hover img {
  transform: scale(2);
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  width:200%;
  height:200%;
}
```

```html
<div id="MapBase" class="map-container map-base dragscroll">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/450x550" class="map">
```

Comment: Thank you daad but I am still unable to scroll up or left on the scaled image. I want to be able to scroll into the negative space after the image has scaled.

I've tried to use `scroll-margin` but had no luck in getting that to work either.